# 90s Teen fantasy novel. Party of warrior, wizard and rogue. A powerful magic gem and a shapeshifting monster

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

Looking for a teen fantasy novel from when I was a kid, unfortunately I can't remember the title or the author. I'm sure it was part of a young adult fantasy series though. Not a trilogy or anything, just a part of a series of individual publications like Point Fantasy. It told the story of 3 adventurers: a warrior, a wizard and a small rogue. The antagonist is a shape-shifting monster. The monster is searching for a magical gem of incredible power and the party of adventurers are trying to stop it.

I seem to recall the cover depicting a landscape, perhaps with a character or two in the foreground looking over it (?). I can remember the cover had a red border.

It was approx 300 pages.

I can recall some scenes:

I think the journey starts with the warrior, alone. He meets the wizard and rogue along the way.

In one section the party is searching a series of caves and are forced to escape after hoards of orcs/goblins discover them and give chase.

There is a beautiful female character that the party discover in a forest clearing. The rogue character falls hopelessly in love with her. Her name is Star. Her origin remains a mystery until the climax when it's revealed she is a shape-shifting monster as well.

One scene takes place in a hot-air balloon. The heroes are trying to escape and this is the moment the beautiful female character reveals her true nature and leaps from the balloon.

The wizard character spends the majority of the story struggling to channel his magic. He often tries to invoke spells that fizzle out. It's not until the climactic battle that he rediscovers his magical prowess.

The final battle between the warrior and wizard against the shapeshifter takes place in a forest glade. The monster has the magical gem and has become immortal, constantly healing its wounds. When the wizard gets his hands on the gem, he is able to tap into its power. He sends the monster flying with just a glance, then he empowers the warriors sword with a white-hot light that prevents the monster from healing his wounds. With the last power within the gem, the wizard captures the monster in a fast-growing tree, sealing it within.

The novel has about a dozen black and white illustrations. I remember the monster depicted as thin, wiry being with many horns and spikes over its body and head.

Comment: Hi again! That's already a good chunk of info but could you maybe take a look at [these guidelines on story-id](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in?

Comment: What can you tell us about the cover of the book? Anything that stands out? Q

Comment: I think it had a silhouette of a warrior in the foreground standing on a rocky outcrop, staring out over a vast landscape

Comment: Solved! I found the book in my dads old collection. To aid anyone who finds this thread I can tell you - with absolute certainty - that my descriptions were waaaay off haha.

Comment: The book is called Shadowmaster, by Ian Livingstone and Marc Gascoigne. I said: "it's not part of a series" (It's actually the last book in a trilogy). I said: "The cover depicts a landscape with characters in the foreground" (It's actually 3 heroes in a hot air balloon fighting off a hoard of monsters as they try to lift off the ground). I said: "The warrior meets the wizard along the way" (They're actually old friends and meet up on purpose). I said: "The antagonist is searching for a magical gem" (The antagonist finds the gem in the first chapter).

Comment: Fun additional fact: The book sells for around $130 on Amazon, for used copies. Seems I've stumbled upon a collectors item :)

Comment: Nice! Please post it as a self-answer below! :)

Comment: So, is it a "choose your own adventure" type book?  That's what Ian Livingstone is famous for.